# Use of a parameter at multiple places in a JDBC PreparedStatement

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm looking to use a value at multiple places in a JDBC `PreparedStatement ps`.

Eg. the condition clause of the query is looking for the value of a single param be in the range [first, last]:

```
"select * from table99 
    where ?>first and ?<last"
```

i simply can assign the param twice:

```
ps.setInt(1, nTimes); 
ps.setInt(2, nTimes);
```

Is there a way of doing this-- like 
marking the parameters to show which ones ought to get the same value?

TIA

Comment: No, you can't. One set*() call for one parameter placeholder. IIRC JDBC doesn't even have named parameters (i.e. `:p1`, `:p2`, ...), but only positional ones.

Comment: @watery - oh. one more reason that I like jpa better. thx for the ans.

Comment: **For this example** you can use `? BETWEEN first+1 AND last-1`, except that square brackets [a,b] conventionally mean *inclusive* bounds which is simpler `? BETWEEN first AND last`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a wrapper around PreparedStatement that can do this.

[Named Parameters for PreparedStatement](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html)

[Copy on github](https://github.com/bnewport/Samples/blob/master/wxsutils/src/main/java/com/devwebsphere/jdbc/loader/NamedParameterStatement.java)

I'll also post the source here for easier access:

```java
package com.devwebsphere.jdbc.loader;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class wraps around a {@link PreparedStatement} and allows the programmer to set parameters by name instead of by
 * index. This eliminates any confusion as to which parameter index represents what. This also means that rearranging
 * the SQL statement or adding a parameter doesn't involve renumbering your indices. Code such as this:
 * 
 * 
 * Connection con=getConnection(); String query="select * from my_table where name=? or address=?"; PreparedStatement
 * p=con.prepareStatement(query); p.setString(1, "bob"); p.setString(2, "123 terrace ct"); ResultSet
 * rs=p.executeQuery();
 * 
 * can be replaced with:
 * 
 * Connection con=getConnection(); String query="select * from my_table where name=:name or address=:address";
 * NamedParameterStatement p=new NamedParameterStatement(con, query); p.setString("name", "bob"); p.setString("address",
 * "123 terrace ct"); ResultSet rs=p.executeQuery();
 * 
 * Sourced from JavaWorld Article @ http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html
 * 
 * @author adam_crume
 */

public class NamedParameterStatement {
    /** The statement this object is wrapping. */
    private final PreparedStatement statement;

    /** Maps parameter names to arrays of ints which are the parameter indices. */
    private Map<String, int[]> indexMap;

    /**
     * Creates a NamedParameterStatement. Wraps a call to c.{@link Connection#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)
     * prepareStatement}.
     * 
     * @param connection
     *            the database connection
     * @param query
     *            the parameterized query
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if the statement could not be created
     */
    public NamedParameterStatement(Connection connection, String query) throws SQLException {
        String parsedQuery = parse(query);
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(parsedQuery);
    }

    /**
     * Parses a query with named parameters. The parameter-index mappings are put into the map, and the parsed query is
     * returned. DO NOT CALL FROM CLIENT CODE. This method is non-private so JUnit code can test it.
     * 
     * @param query
     *            query to parse
     * @param paramMap
     *            map to hold parameter-index mappings
     * @return the parsed query
     */
    final String parse(String query) {
        // I was originally using regular expressions, but they didn't work well for ignoring
        // parameter-like strings inside quotes.
        int length = query.length();
        StringBuffer parsedQuery = new StringBuffer(length);
        boolean inSingleQuote = false;
        boolean inDoubleQuote = false;
        int index = 1;
        HashMap<String, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = query.charAt(i);
            if (inSingleQuote) {
                if (c == '\'') {
                    inSingleQuote = false;
                }
            } else if (inDoubleQuote) {
                if (c == '"') {
                    inDoubleQuote = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (c == '\'') {
                    inSingleQuote = true;
                } else if (c == '"') {
                    inDoubleQuote = true;
                } else if (c == ':' && i + 1 < length && Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(query.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    int j = i + 2;
                    while (j < length && Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(query.charAt(j))) {
                        j++;
                    }
                    String name = query.substring(i + 1, j);
                    c = '?'; // replace the parameter with a question mark
                    i += name.length(); // skip past the end if the parameter

                    List<Integer> indexList = indexes.get(name);
                    if (indexList == null) {
                        indexList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                        indexes.put(name, indexList);
                    }
                    indexList.add(Integer.valueOf(index));

                    index++;
                }
            }
            parsedQuery.append(c);
        }

        indexMap = new HashMap<String, int[]>(indexes.size());
        // replace the lists of Integer objects with arrays of ints
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : indexes.entrySet()) {
            List<Integer> list = entry.getValue();
            int[] intIndexes = new int[list.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (Integer x : list) {
                intIndexes[i++] = x.intValue();
            }
            indexMap.put(entry.getKey(), intIndexes);
        }

        return parsedQuery.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the indexes for a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @return parameter indexes
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     */
    private int[] getIndexes(String name) {
        int[] indexes = indexMap.get(name);
        if (indexes == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter not found: " + name);
        }
        return indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @param value
     *            parameter value
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     * @see PreparedStatement#setObject(int, java.lang.Object)
     */
    public void setObject(String name, Object value) throws SQLException {
        int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            statement.setObject(indexes[i], value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @param value
     *            parameter value
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     * @see PreparedStatement#setString(int, java.lang.String)
     */
    public void setString(String name, String value) throws SQLException {
        int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            statement.setString(indexes[i], value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @param value
     *            parameter value
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     * @see PreparedStatement#setInt(int, int)
     */
    public void setInt(String name, int value) throws SQLException {
        int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            statement.setInt(indexes[i], value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @param value
     *            parameter value
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     * @see PreparedStatement#setInt(int, int)
     */
    public void setLong(String name, long value) throws SQLException {
        int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            statement.setLong(indexes[i], value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets a parameter.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            parameter name
     * @param value
     *            parameter value
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if the parameter does not exist
     * @see PreparedStatement#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp)
     */
    public void setTimestamp(String name, Timestamp value) throws SQLException {
        int[] indexes = getIndexes(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            statement.setTimestamp(indexes[i], value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the underlying statement.
     * 
     * @return the statement
     */
    public PreparedStatement getStatement() {
        return statement;
    }

    /**
     * Executes the statement.
     * 
     * @return true if the first result is a {@link ResultSet}
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @see PreparedStatement#execute()
     */
    public boolean execute() throws SQLException {
        return statement.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Executes the statement, which must be a query.
     * 
     * @return the query results
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @see PreparedStatement#executeQuery()
     */
    public ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException {
        return statement.executeQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Executes the statement, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns
     * nothing, such as a DDL statement.
     * 
     * @return number of rows affected
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @see PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()
     */
    public int executeUpdate() throws SQLException {
        return statement.executeUpdate();
    }

    /**
     * Closes the statement.
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if an error occurred
     * @see Statement#close()
     */
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        statement.close();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the current set of parameters as a batch entry.
     * 
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if something went wrong
     */
    public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
        statement.addBatch();
    }

    /**
     * Executes all of the batched statements.
     * 
     * See {@link Statement#executeBatch()} for details.
     * 
     * @return update counts for each statement
     * @throws SQLException
     *             if something went wrong
     */
    public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException {
        return statement.executeBatch();
    }
}
```